# Two application pools or root virtual directories under one site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment, iis-7

This might sound like a very dumb question, so let me first say what I want to achieve and then proceed to my question on how I'd envision something like this working.

I am trying to achieve completely seamless deploys of our web application to IIS (without interrupting users or active connections).

The way I envision this working is to have two root virtual directories sharing the same site. By root virtual directory I mean the one that IIS creates internally and assigns it to the root of each site or web application; except here I want to have two such root vdirs (each bound to their own app pool, but both referencing the exact same application from **different** folders). During normal operation, one of the vdirs would be inactive.

When doing a deployment, I would put the new code into another folder referenced by the second (inactive) vdir, and then mark it as active. What I want to accomplish is to then have IIS begin sending all **new** connections (requesting the **same** site) to that second vdir with the new code, but keeping the old one also alive & active until all remaining connections to it are dead (some, such as file uploads, could be long running). Once all of the lingering connections are dead, the old vdir/app pool becomes inactive and the second one with the new code becomes the only active one.

I hope this makes sense.

If it does not, here is my alternative attempt at explaining it with an example.

```
--- Web Site ("mysite.com")
    --- Root VDir#1 (IIS Internal, App Pool: AppPool#1, Virtual Path: /, Physical Path: C:\inetpub\MySite.v1084\). ACTIVE
    --- Root VDir#2 (IIS Internal, App Pool: AppPool#2, Virtual Path: /, Physical Path: NONE). INACTIVE
```

During a deployment, Root VDir#2 would become active and its Physical Path would change to C:\inetpub\MySite.v1085. That would be the default vdir IIS would serve for all new connections. Once all active sessions/connections to Root VDir#1 die, that becomes inactive.

Is something like this possible? Are there alternative ways of doing something like this (I know there is some form of built-in load balancing in IIS ("Web Farms"?) but am not too familiar with it).

Comment: If you persist any state in server memory between requests, this won't work. In-memory session usage is the most obvious one, but there could be other more subtle. Make sure that you do not have them.

Comment: We do not... Partly because we have complete hardware-level load balancing in production and partly from a dependence on some in-house legacy systems, we do not store any state information at all on the web server (even session information is handled by third party cache server clusters).

Comment: Erm. If you have a load balancer then I don't understand a problem. Divert all traffic to a single node (let the old connections die). Update all the other nodes. Divert traffic to updated nodes (let the old connections die). Update the last one. Enable it back. Will this work?

Comment: Heh, yes, this is currently exactly what we do in Production :) However, I also want to achieve full seamlessness on our Dev, QA and client-facing sandbox environments as well, of which we have quite a few and they all run on single web servers.

Comment: Also google finds these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148084/how-to-deploy-an-asp-net-application-with-zero-downtime
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071228/best-practice-for-updating-a-live-website-running-on-iis
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358020/seamless-deployment-in-asp-net-iis-kills-worker-process-before-new-worker-proce
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521208/is-smooth-deployment-possible-with-componentized-asp-net-mvc-apps#4526754
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028932/deploying-asp-net-to-single-server-without-service-interruption

Comment: And these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685346/how-do-i-deploy-an-application-to-iis-while-that-web-application-is-running
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697552/publishing-uploading-new-dll-to-iis-website-goes-down-whilst-uploading

Comment: Get your management to pay for an additional server for each environment and load balance them. I'm sure you can use inexpensive software load balancer for those =) Nowaday when most environments (even dev and QA) are hosted in the VMs anyway it's usually trivial. =)

Comment: Yes, I actually haven't thought of using a software-based load balancer. Thanks for the tip! Having two servers per environment may eventually be the route we will end up taking; I was just wondering if there are simpler solutions that would allow us to keep one server. I am currently managing close to 15(!) full environments, all of which have an incredible amount of moving parts (years of homegrown legacy systems written in all platforms imaginable). Having full redundancy on these means replicating all of the non-.NET portions as well (which is about 75% of our application), which leads me

Comment: to investigate a possibly easier solution first considering that .NET is the only part of the site that has this issue...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24794/discussion-between-zespri-and-ruslan)

Comment: Apologies, I was sidetracked with other projects. Let me know if this is still something you would be interested in discussing in more depth.

Answer (score 1):

What you are proposing sounds like an A/B swap.  ([Similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/151338/fast-swapping-of-production-and-staging-in-iis))

There is an IIS addin tool [**from Microsoft called Web Deploy**](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy).  It will automate most of the physical motions of deploying updated code into IIS but your requirement of seamless migration is the sticky point because you have long-running file-transactions.  The best way to handle this is to get a load balancer, run with two production instances of your site at the same time and have a third instance for staging updates.

(BTW, Azure is doing something like this with "Cloud Services" -- there's a "Swap" command to do this exact thing.)

Going back to your particular setup, consider this configuration:

One IIS machine, two Web Sites.  Web Site A and Web Site B.  They do not point to the same files.  They have their own folders.  Web Site A is online and serving users in production, while Web Site B is offline.  When you are ready to update, you update Web Site B, then swap On/Off Web Site A.  Now B is online and A is offline.  This is an A/B rotation.  Later, when you do your next update, you update A, then swap On/Off with B.  Now A is online and B is offline.

That exact moment, when you swap, there is the possibility of losing traffic -- (and you will probably kill those file transfers) but if your app is low volume, maybe no one will notice (you decide).  However, if this is mission critical, high volume, site -- get a load balancer and use it as others have described.

What WebDeploy won't do, (as far as I know) is swap On/Off site A and site B.  For that, you'll need to [**write a script and do it at the command line**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772137%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

The benefit of the Web Deploy + scripts is that you can eventually automate this and maybe tie it into a continuous deployment system.

The long running file transfers are probably impossible to save with this setup.  Another challenge is any in-memory state of your app.  If your web app was designed with in-memory data, then you'll lose it when you do the A/B swap.  If the programmers are using session, you may be able to turn on the session service.  The session data will not be in the same process with the rest of the app and might survive the A/B swap.  Talk to your programmers about how the app manages in-memory data.  Maybe it doesn't actually have any.  Maybe it can be easily recreated once the app reloads -- (e.g. rebuilding a cache from database)